# I am using Halcogen to generate LLD for TMS570LS0914. But it seems like there are only 64 Message Objects for each CAN channel

Tags: can, tms570

I am using Halcogen to generate LLD for TMS570LS0914. But it seems like there are only 64 Message Objects for each CAN channel.

Q1. How to transmit/receive more than 64 CAN messages on single CAN channel?

Q2. Is there any example code for the same? If yes, please share

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. How to transmit/receive more than 64 CAN messages on single CAN channel?

The idea is to use a combination of identifier and mask bits to configure the channels to your needs.

[image]
<sub>Source: [TMS570LS09x/07x Technical Reference Manual
, page 1236](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu607a/spnu607a.pdf#page=1236)</sub>

For very high priority messages you could set all mask bits to match one specific message identifier. And for low priority messages you would set the mask bits to allow a large range of message identifiers.

For more information see [SPNA131](https://www.ti.com/lit/fs/spna131/spna131.pdf?).

> Q2. Is there any example code for the same?

TI provides [HALCoGen](https://www.ti.com/tool/HALCOGEN) to generate HAL code for the TMS570.